# Google ColorPicker library for Android error: compileSdkVersion is not specified

Tags: android, build.gradle

There are many StackOverflow threads about this topic, asking for different frameworks, the most of them has been solved for that specific framework giving versions needed, dependencies and additional libraries to work, so, now I want to try [this colorpicker from google](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/colorpicker) and none of those answers works for me.

So, I would like to make it work of course, but I also would like to know how you guys know what a framework needs to work.

This is my build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nextu.dialogos"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':colorpicker')
}
```

This is the build.gradle of the colorpicker:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    sourceSets.main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
}
```

Comment: post the `build.gradle` file for the colorpicker library

Comment: Done, do you think I should add the compilesdkversion there?

Comment: need to add `compileSdkVersion` for the library too

Comment: I added compileSdkVersion 28 and buildToolsVersion "28.0.3" but it continues showing the same error message, did I write it right?